# TightVNC shows the window cropped

Tags: qemu, tightvnc

I am running debian live cd in qemu (kvm), and when I connect to VNC via `vncviewer localhost:5900` the window is cropped to some static width and height combination. Making window fullscreen or resizing it doesn’t have any effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same screen when installing Debian in a virtual machine, I eventually found that when I disconnected and reconnected after the initial boot screen, it would be the correct size.

It seems the reason for the cropped screen was that TightVNC wasn't resizing when the vm was.

So my bad solution is to close the client whenever there's a screen resize.

Specifically for installing Debian on a vm, you have to connect once to select "install" from the splash screen, then disconnect and reconnect so that TightVNC gets the new screen size.

I'm sure there's a better solution if you look into it.

[image]